# Use extremely small number in affine.Affine in python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, affinetransform

The small number in Affine.scale always equal to zero

For example,

```
from affine import Affine

# This line will show
#| 0.00, 0.00, 0.00|
#| 0.00, 0.00, 0.00|
#| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
print(Affine.scale(1/(2**19)))
```

However, I need 1.9073486328125e-06 instead of 0.

How can I fix this?

(The version of the affine I use is 2.3.0.)

Comment: It's solved now. But I can accept your own answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print an affine transformation metrix will make it print the rounded number.

We should use index to get the exact number stored in the metirx.

```
print(Affine.scale(1/(2**19))[0])
# got: 1.9073486328125e-06
```